# Firebase Cloud function not updating data in Firestore database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I'm writing a scheduled cloud function that is supposed to run every minute and update certain values in my Firestore database. I'm getting a success on the function and I don't see any errors, however, the database isn't updating. My project is made with flutter but I wrote the cloud function with node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdKcS.png)

This is my cloud function code.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.myScheduledCloudFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').timeZone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur').onRun(async (context) => {
   
    admin.firestore().collection('users').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('habits').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(habitDoc) {
                    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(doc.uid).collection('habits').doc(habitDoc.id).ref.update({ 
                        'iscompleted' : false,
                        'completedcount': 0
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })

    return null;
});
```

I feel like it might be related to the rules but I'm not sure, for now my rules are default I haven't changed them. I hope someone can help

Comment: functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *'), shouldn't this be something like '* 1 * *  *' for minutes (or whichever * position represent the minutes position)?

Comment: @MZM no its actually * * * * * u can check https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_* and according to firebase, the function is running "successfully" every minute. but the data in firestore isn't updating :(

Comment: Your code is ignoring all the promises from calls to `update`. This will make any Cloud Function behave unpredictably, as it will shut down async work before it completes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Doug Stevenson I've learned that I wasn't giving any time for the async functions to take its course. I have fixed my work and now it is working.

here's the fixed code:

```js
exports.myScheduledCloudFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').timeZone('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur').onRun(async (context) => {
   
    const querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get();
    querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const habitQuerySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('habits').get();
        habitQuerySnapshot.forEach(async (habitDoc) => {
            
            if (doc && doc.ref) {
              
              await habitDoc.ref.update({ 
                'iscompleted' : false,
                'completedcount': 0
              });
            }
        });
    });

    return null;
});
```